# Description suivant une question : où mettre le point d'interrogation ?

Tags: questions, ponctuation

Quelle est la syntaxe à adopter lorsqu'on veut suivre une question d'une description ?

Exemple : N'aurait-il pas été possible de  faire ceci : .....

Faut-il mettre le point d'interrogation après l'exemple, ou après **ceci** ? Dans ce dernier cas, où placer les deux points ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À mon humble avis, c'est un emploi incorrect à plusieurs égards. Le [deux-points](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deux-points) s'apparente au *point-virgule*, donc il sépare des propositions. Il peut aussi introduire, sans le concours d'aucun mot particulier, une *citation*, une *explication/cause*, une *conséquence/synthèse* ou une *énumération*. Il n'est pas fait mention de la description. Dans un autre ordre d'idée, une «description» n'est pas un [*type de phrase*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase#Types_de_phrases), alors que c'est le cas pour la *phrase interrogative*. Le deux-points n'est pas requis pour décrire quoi que ce soit. La description est un *sens*, que les propositions articulent.

Le [*point d'interrogation*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_d%27interrogation) est un élément de ponctuation qui termine une phrase. Mais comment peut-on rendre phonétiquement une interrogation après une énumération de termes égaux? comment ceci laisse-t-il une possibilité d'[*intonation prosodique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_prosodique)? L'énumération d'un seul élément(!) ne constitue certainement pas une norme à mon humble avis. On peut énumérer en mode interrogatif, mais il faut appliquer le point d'interrogation sur les éléments(« De quelle couleur était-il ? bleu ? rouge ? vert ? » - la personne essaye de deviner, il s'agit presque d'une virgule avec quatre questions). C'est différent de qui est envisagé ici.

Mais justement, [*ceci*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ceci) quoi? Souvent, ce pronom démonstratif [réfère](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_d%C3%A9monstratif) à un énoncé antérieur, à quelque chose à proximité, physiquement on conceptuellement. Bien évidemment, *ceci* suivi du deux-points peut facilement introduire une proposition se terminant par un point d'interrogation:

> J'ai entendu ceci: «Ne dis rien à personne, compris?»
>
> Je voulais te dire ceci: - Ne dis rien à personne, compris?

Il s'agit de citations. Hormis les cas mentionnés, le seul cas où *ceci* semble utilisé alors qu'on ne sait pas encore ce dont il s'agit c'est avec un objet physique("ceci est à moi [montrer l'objet] "). La forme proposée est peut-être une forme de juxtaposition, une [*parataxe*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxe)? Ou un calque d'un truc comme *couldn't we do this*? La forme négative et le temps du verbe sont inappropriés ici, et c'est un réflexe à proscrire. Dans un contexte de réflexion rhétorique suggestive sur son passé, du genre "n'aurait-il pas été souhaitable de ne pas se marier si jeune? 40 ans déjà!", ça marche peut-être, mais pas lors d'un dialogue contemporain entre deux personnes selon moi...

---

Je pense qu' il est préférable de privilégier:

> Voici ce que j'aurais voulu faire: (explication).
>   Ceci est-il toujours possible?/Est-ce toujours possible?
>
> ou
>
> > Est-il possible de payer à l'avance, ce qui m'éviterait bien des soucis?
> >
> > Est-il possible de payer à l'avance? ça m'éviterait bien
> >     des soucis?
> >
> > Est-il possible de payer à l'avance? Ça
> >     m'éviterait bien des soucis!

Comment: Réponse très documentée, mais ne faut-il pas lire : "Voici ***ce*** que j'aurais voulu faire: (explication)." ?

Comment: @cl-r Absolument; merci de l'avoir remarqué! J'ai corrigé.

Answer (score 1):

> Je pense qu'il doit être possible de faire comme vous l'indiquez:
>   mettre le point à la fin ?

Ça doit certainement aussi être lié un peu à la longueur de la question et de la description. Si la description est trop longue, il est, je pense, préférable de ne pas faire oublier la question et de placer le point d'interrogation avant.